# Using GeometryReader without modifying the view

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader

I am trying to use `GeometryReader` here to build views based on the size available, however because this view is embedded in a parent view with padding, it is not drawing correctly.  I know from [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724052/swiftui-how-to-calculate-a-views-size-based-on-its-frames-size-without-using), some have said to use the `GeometryReader` as an `.overlay` or `.background` but I can't figure out a way to do that here:

```
 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(dataStore.sleepOrAwakeSpans) { sleepOrAwakeSpan in
                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * CGFloat((sleepOrAwakeSpan.endTime.timeIntervalSince(sleepOrAwakeSpan.startTime) / athlyticDataStore.sleepOrAwakeSpans.map { $0.endTime.timeIntervalSince($0.startTime) }.reduce(0, +))), height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(sleepOrAwakeSpan.asleep == false ? TrackerConstants.scaleLevel6Color : TrackerConstants.scaleLevel2Color)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do here. Most folks recommend using a GeometryReader as an overlay/background view because it then uses the size available from the parent view. When GeometryReader is used like above, it will attempt to use up all space available in the view, within which it will fill with it's child views.

Comment: your codes does not compile

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var body: some View {
    Color.clear.overlay(     // << consumes available space of parent
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(dataStore.sleepOrAwakeSpans) { sleepOrAwakeSpan in
                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * CGFloat((sleepOrAwakeSpan.endTime.timeIntervalSince(sleepOrAwakeSpan.startTime) / athlyticDataStore.sleepOrAwakeSpans.map { $0.endTime.timeIntervalSince($0.startTime) }.reduce(0, +))), height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(sleepOrAwakeSpan.asleep == false ? TrackerConstants.scaleLevel6Color : TrackerConstants.scaleLevel2Color)
                    }
                }
            }
        })     // end of overlay
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as long as the HStack spacing is 0, but when I try to add more space between each RoundedRectangle (e.g. 5 in my example) it flows almost all the way off the screen.  How can I account for the spacing? 